# Tagging hardware qn about Mac Mini Server

Tags: discussion, tags

Asked on [chat](http://chat.superuser.com/transcript/message/22276#22276):

> Tagging question: what are the right tags for qns about Mac Mini, Server edition? I've seen using [mac-mini](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini) and [server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/server) together, but there's also [osx-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-server), and maybe a new tag, [mac-mini-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini-server) is justified, since some folk use it with linux, and not as a server?

I've reasked here, at Ivo's request.

I asked the question that led to this one: [Can Mac Mini Server be booted off either of its two disks?](https://superuser.com/questions/210953/can-mac-mini-server-be-booted-off-either-of-its-two-disks), and added the new [mac-mini-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini-server), so this question is post hoc: should that tag exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [osx-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-server) + [mac-mini](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini) makes for a better tag combination - that would indicate OS X server running on Mac Mini, ergo, Mac Mini server on OS X, else [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux) + [mac-mini](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini) to indicate Linux running on Mac Mini

Then again, I'm not familiar on Apple technologies that much so let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: That sounds ... eminently sensible.  I had not though of the usefulness of the [linux] tag.  I've edited the qn's tags.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning the question @Charles